# how to remove additional tag from json array?

Tags: php, json, wordpress

I'm getting additional terms when i try to fetch data from a wordpress website.

```
    function get_data($url)
    {
      $ch = curl_init();
      $timeout = 20;
      curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
      curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
      curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,$timeout);
      $data = curl_exec($ch);
      curl_close($ch);
      return $data;
    }

$uname=$_GET['uname'];
$pwd=$_GET['pwd'];

    $root_url = "http://domain.com/";
    $nonce_url = $root_url."api/get_nonce/?controller=auth&method=generate_auth_cookie";
    $json = get_data($nonce_url);
    $json_data =  json_decode(substr($json,3), true);

    // check that user is logged into WP
    $nonce = $json_data['nonce']; // need to have an exception handler in case this fails

echo $json;
```

and the output is,

```
    ï»¿ï»¿{"status":"ok","controller":"auth","method":"generate_auth_cookie","nonce":"3ca4ad3a80"}
```

how can I remove ï»¿ï»¿ this additional term from the json array?

Comment: but its working when i try it in localhost.

Comment: Something is probably wrong with a plugin or theme. This looks like it might be a `BOM` (byte-order mark). Check your encoding on your output. Also, disable all plugins and themes and see if the behavior persists.

Comment: ya you are correct. Pie register plugin causes this problem. Thanks